# unexpected EOF while parsing on line that has nothing

Tags: python, parsing, eof

[Why do I keep getting this error message when there is nothing on that line?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKydr.png)

How come I keep getting this error message? There is literally nothing in the line (pic included) so I don't understand why I keep getting these messages. the only things I have in this program are:

```
SURVEY QUESTION = "(insert question)"
SURVEY_RESULTS = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

and

```
print(SURVEY_RESULTS)
```

Nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Try removing that empty comment `#`

Comment: There's nothing in the screenshot or the code you posted that would let us figure out the problem. We can't help you without a [mcve].

Comment: The Space in your first variable could be causing a problem.

Comment: I get an "invalid syntax" error from the spot that @KuboMD mentioned. The comments in the actual file must be changing things up somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what it's telling you. Unexpected EOF. That means it is trying to find the end of some previous construct in your code above, and not finding it. Perhaps an unterminated string literal, or a function missing an ending right-paren.

Perhaps it's the missing underscore in `SURVEY QUESTION`.

Comment: I added an underscore and it still seems to be giving me the error

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on then. Your code works for me, with the missing underscore added. Perhaps Juan Diego Garcia's comment about the empty `#` comment is worth looking into.